# query string search is not working

Tags: elasticsearch

Hi I am using the not analyzed over the field

but when i search with the below query

```
 "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "06H121605E",
      "default_field": "invoiceID"
    }
  }
}
```

I am getting 2 documents in results

but when I went for the wild card

its giving me hits as null

```
 "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "06H121605*",
      "default_field": "invoiceID"
    }
  }
```

Here is my mapping for the invoiceID field

```
 "invoiceID": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
               },
```

Query:

```
GET ordersdetails/_search
{
 "size": 1000, 
 "query": {
   "query_string": {
     "query": "06H121605E\\*",
     "default_field": "invoiceID",
     "analyze_wildcard": true
   }
 }
}
```

OUTPUT

```
{
   "took": 5,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 0,
      "max_score": null,
      "hits": []
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the version 5.2.1 your query works you can as well use:

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string" : { 
            "query" : "06H121605*",
            "default_field": "invoiceID",
            "analyze_wildcard": true
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the reference:

[Documentation query string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html)

Comment: Hi Mel thanks for your remarks .!!!!! but in the second query m using the wildcard character *, for this m getting hit as null  should I  go for standard analyzer or index: not_analyzed in mapping

Comment: "query": {
   "query_string": {
     "query": "06H121605*",
     "default_field": "partNumber",
     "analyze_wildcard": true
   }
 }

Comment: Still using * in search term and analyze wild card : true combination is giving me hits as Null

Comment: Try to escape the * by doing \\\* in your query

Comment: No luck with using escape sequence, Mel :(

Comment: Can you add some example in your question for me to test easily

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138029/discussion-between-prasad-khandagale-and-mel).